# Django Rest Framework Read-Only Field Issue

Tags: python, django, rest, serialization, slug

I am learning DRF and I encountered one issue. I have slug field in the model which I want to be slugified from the title. The issue is I can`t complete this auto-population whatever ways I tried. I have created custom save method in model like this:

```
class PostObjects(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(status="published")


class Post(models.Model):
    options = (("draft", "Draft"), ("published", "Published"))
    
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    excerpt = models.TextField(null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique_for_date="published")
    published = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts"
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=options, default="published")
    objects = models.Manager()
    postobjects = PostObjects()
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ("-published",)
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Then I tried making the field read only with couple of ways in Serializer.py:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.ReadOnlyField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ("id", "title", "author", "excerpt", "content", "status", "slug")
        #read_only_fields = ["slug"]
        #extra_kwargs = {'slug': {'read_only': True}}
```

All three ways (ReadOnlyField, read_only_fields, extra_kwargs) give me error that slug is required. I also tried to create custom "perform_create" in views so I can supply this slugify to .save method but no result again, as is.valid gives false

[image: This is the error I am getting]

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: Hi, just to be sure, can you post the error you get? Are you writing UT to show the issue ?

Comment: @MassimoCosta Hello, I have added a screenshot with error. I am sorry I didnt understand what you mean by UT

Comment: UT (Unit Test) sorry I was too short :D

Comment: not sure about `ReadOnlyField()`, the documentation said it automatically generated. in your commented code there's a type.
It should be `read_only_fields` instead of `read_only_field`

Comment: it was read_only_fields actually. It is my bad fatfingered while commenting.

Answer (score 1):

not sure why it's failing your side.
Just tried this quick example

```py
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify


# Create your models here.
class MyModel(models.Model):

    title = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

```py
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import MyModel


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        read_only_fields = ('slug', )
        fields = '__all__'
```

```py
# views.py
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import MyModel
from .serializers import MyModelSerializer

# Create your views here.
class MyView(generics.CreateAPIView):

    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

and works for me

Comment: Alright, So I think I understood what is the reason. "unique_for_date" attribute in SlugField is creating the issue. I removed it and it worked well. Thanks a lot for help. I know there is constraint mentioned in DRF website about "unique_together" but nothing about "unique_for_date"